# Listening for dataChange event in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: flex4, advanceddatagrid

This is my code:

```
<controls:AdvancedDataGrid id="adg" dataChange="adg_dataChangeHandler(event)">
      <!-- other stuff goes here -->
</controls:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

and in my ActionScript code:

```
protected function adg_dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
  trace(1);
}
```

When I edit a cell in advancedDataGrid (making the columns editable of course) it never dispatches an event. Or, in other words, my function is never called. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried adding an event listener to the dataProviders COLLECTION_CHANGE event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the better option for my scenario is to use an itemEditor, that has a listener put on the change event. Code looks like :

```
<controls:AdvancedDataGrid id="adg">
   <controls:groupedColumns>
      <adgs:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="A" wordWrap="true" dataField="name" editable="false" itemEditor="Aaa"/>
    </controls:groupedColumns>
</controls:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

and the item editor class is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TextInput xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
              xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" change="textinput1_changeHandler(event)" restrict="0-9">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function textinput1_changeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                trace("ha");
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</mx:TextInput>
```